# How to get Map value given a key in a JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have a Struts 2 application using the JSTL/Struts2/DisplayTag tag libraries in my JSP.  Is there a way to access the value of a Map in a JSP given the key?

```
// Action code
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();

mapOnValueStack = map;

//add key/value pairs

fieldKeyOnValueStack = "1";//sets key
```

....

```
<%-- JSP code --%>

<s:property value="%{mapOnValueStack.get(fieldKeyOnValueStack)}" />
```

Essentially I want to do map access within the JSP.  **Is this possible?**

Thanks!

Comment: The `%{ }` things (called OGNL) are not specific to JSP/JSTL. They are specific to Struts2. This question is therefore very confusing for non-Struts2 developers, given the "try this" answers which may not be correct at all. In normal JSP you would use EL `${mapOnValueStack[fieldKeyOnValueStack]}` for this. Yet your code example doesn't give away that those variables are available as `${mapOnValueStack}` and `${fieldKeyOnValueStack}` in normal JSP EL scope.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but I state in the question that it is a Struts 2 application and that I am using JSTL, Struts 2, and Display Tag libraries.  I, then, assume anybody answering the question knows the difference between them.  '%{mapOnValueStack.get(fieldKeyOnValueStack)}' is only correct inside of the Struts 2 tag.  It was just an example of what I was trying to express.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you try this :

```
<s:property value="%{mapOnValueStack.['fieldKeyOnValueStack']}" />
```

Comment: Is there really a period before the `[`?

Comment: And you don't need the %{} if the map is on the value stack.

Answer (score 5):

If You have used this in your action,

```
Map<String,Integer> headerMap=new HashMap<String, Integer>();
headerMap.put("INITIATED", 0);
headerMap.put("COMPLETED", 0);
headerMap.put("SUBMITTED", 0);
headerMap.put("APPROVED", 0);
headerMap.put("TRAFICKED", 0);
headerMap.put("REJECTED", 0);
```

Then use this on your jsp,

```
<s:property value="%{headerMap.INITIATED}" />
<s:property value="%{headerMap.REJECTED}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<s:property value="%{mapOnValueStack['fieldKeyOnValueStack']}" />
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${mapOnValueStack}">
    Name:  ${entry.key} <br/>
    Value: ${entry.value}
</c:forEach>
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a way to access a value in a map by its key.  This solution iterates through all key/value pairs and makes no distinction between the keys.