# How to get a Map value if the key is a Boolean data type in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

Related to the questions [How to get map value given a key in a JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264774/how-to-get-map-value-given-a-key-in-a-jsp) and [Get value of HashMap by specific key in EL without iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395308/get-value-of-hashmap-by-specific-key-in-el-without-iterating-over-it)

I have a `HashMap<Boolean, String>` and get always a null in the property tag. How do I get the string value given a Boolean key?

```
<s:property value="%{map['keyValueStack']}"></s:property>
```

Comment: <s:property value="%{map['true']}"/>, what ideally you should be doing is keep string as key and value boolean. HashMap<String, Boolean>

Comment: Does it make sense to use a map for just two values?

Comment: @SuchandraT, that's accurate for my situation. Many thanks! :)

Comment: Yes, @aled, it is for a select tag.